# Tkinter GUI Updating Toplevel Window

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

```
from tkinter import*
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import filedialog
import time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import re
import tkinter.font as font


root=Tk()
root.geometry("700x900+500+250")

my_notebook = ttk.Notebook(root)
my_notebook.pack()
my_frame1=Frame(my_notebook,width=500,height=500)


my_frame1.pack(fill="both",expand=1)


my_notebook.add(my_frame1,text="my menu")




def open_popup(choice):
   choice == value_inside.get()
   if choice==options_list[0]:
       
        top= Toplevel(root)
        top.geometry("750x250")
        top.title(choice)
        Label(top, text= "1", font=('Mistral 18 bold')).place(x=150,y=80)
   elif choice==options_list[1]:
       
        top= Toplevel(root)
        top.geometry("750x250")
        top.title(choice)
        Label(top, text= "2", font=('Mistral 18 bold')).place(x=150,y=80)
          
   elif choice==options_list[2]:
        top= Toplevel(root)
        top.geometry("750x250")
        top.title(choice)
        Label(top, text= "3", font=('Mistral 18 bold')).place(x=150,y=80)
   elif choice==options_list[3]:
        top= Toplevel(root)
        top.geometry("750x250")
        top.title(choice)
        Label(top, text= "4", font=('Mistral 18 bold')).place(x=150,y=80)
   elif choice==options_list[4]:
        top= Toplevel(root)
        top.geometry("750x250")
        top.title(choice)
        Label(top, text= "5", font=('Mistral 18 bold')).place(x=150,y=80)
   elif choice==options_list[5]:
        top= Toplevel(root)
        top.geometry("750x250")
        top.title(choice)
        Label(top, text= "6", font=('Mistral 18 bold')).place(x=150,y=80)
   elif choice==options_list[6]:
        top= Toplevel(root)
        top.geometry("750x250")
        top.title(choice)
        Label(top, text= "7", font=('Mistral 18 bold')).place(x=150,y=80)
     
       
options_list = ["Bz Vs R", "Bz Vs Z", "Br Vs R", "Br Vs Z","|B| Vs R", "|B| Vs Z","B Contour Map"]
value_inside = StringVar()
value_inside.set("B-field Types")
B_field_option=OptionMenu(my_frame1,value_inside,*options_list,command=open_popup)
B_field_option.place(x=110,y=190)
root.mainloop()
```

Hello people,

We have been trying to build a GUI using Tkinter. Everything is OK except when we are trying to open up a new toplevel, the previous one stays also opened. We want to close the previous toplevel (i.e. previous option) when we select a new option. In other words, we want to update what is going on in the toplevel without opening up a new one.

We would be glad if you could help us.

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: You could simply configure the Label and the title instead of creating a new one. Don't you?

Comment: Could you be more clear about what you mean by configuring the label? Sorry if my question is silly but I am rather new to Tkinter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you need to open multiple windows if only one choice is allowed at a time and that value from `value_inside.get()` is always used as the window titile. I imagine you could simply instantiate a single `Toplevel` window whenever a choice is made

```
top = None


def open_popup(top):  # pass in 'top'
   choice = value_inside.get()
   if top == None or not Toplevel.winfo_exists(top):
       top = Toplevel(root)
       top.geometry("750x250")
       top.title(choice )
   else:
       top.configure(title=choice)  # update the existing window
   Label(top, text= "1", font=('Mistral 18 bold')).place(x=150,y=80)
```

Then modify `B_field_option` slightly to include `top` as a parameter

```
B_field_option=OptionMenu(
    my_frame1,
    value_inside,
    *options_list,
    command=lambda t=top: open_popup(t)
)
```

Comment: Because for each option we will fill the pop-up window with different entries and labels. What we want is a single Toplevel that takes the shape (entries, labels etc.) of the option whenever an option is chosen. I think that if we do not pass the choice (i.e. different options) into the open_popup() function we will not be able to achieve that.

Comment: Ah, that wasn't apparent from the question and is a bit more complicated indeed...

Comment: Thanks for the reply! When I run the code with your modification it says "NameError: name 'tk' is not defined".

Comment: Ah, that's my error - I assumed you had done `import tkinter as tk` and not `from tkinter import *` . You'll want to change `tk.Toplevel.winfo_exists(top)` to `Toplevel.winfo_exists(top)` (remove the `tk.` namespace prefix) - Answer edited!

Comment: This code might work, if you would name the toplevel by choice and checks the existence by nametowidget. In addition you should make  the Label text as index+1 of the options_list, to generate the same output as OP.

Comment: Those are fair points!